# Google Chrome Extensions / Webstore

Tags: discussion

I have created a proposal on Area51 for all things todo with Google Chrome Extensions and the coming soon Google Chrome WebStore, I was wondering whether you guys would support this or whether you think those type of questions should be better posted in this Stack Exchange variation.

The link is as follows: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10910/google-chrome-extensions-webstore

Loving the Area51 interface by the way! And congrats guys on being the first one Live!

Comment: The referenced proposal has now been deleted. Closing as "too localised".